Chaning QOpenGLWidget's parent from QMainWindow to QMdiSubWindow is not working properly
I am working on CAD project using Qt OpenGL and implemented views as sub views of QMdiArea.
I did detach view from QMdiArea to a new top widget(QMainWindow) using setCentralWidget and setParent function in Qt5.12 and it is working well.
QMdiSubWindow* sw = (QMdiSubWindow*)m_mdiArea->activeSubWindow();
QTBVizWidget* view = (QTBVizWidget*)sw->widget();
QRect widgetRect = view->geometry();
widgetRect.moveTopLeft(view->parentWidget()->mapToGlobal(widgetRect.topLeft()));
DetachedWindow* newWid = new DetachedWindow(nullptr, view);
if (minimized)
    view->showNormal();
else
    newWid->setGeometry(widgetRect);
newWid->setCentralWidget(view);
view->setParent(newWid);
newWid->showNormal();
view->update();
m_mdiArea->removeSubWindow(sw);

But I am not able to do vice versa, i.e I can't reattach the view from QMainWidget to QMdiArea even I created a new QSubWindow and changed parent, etc.
The main issue is that after the GL view is displayed inside Mdi area, QMainWindow is not closed.
Once I tried to forcely close the empty QMainWindow, the view inside the mdi area also closing.
QMdiSubWindow* sw = new QMdiSubWindow;
sw->setWidget(VizWidget);
sw->setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow);
sw->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
VizWidget->setParent(sw);
QRect widgetRect = VizWidget->geometry();
VizWidget->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, widgetRect.width(), widgetRect.height()));
VizWidget->move(QPoint(0, 0));
detachWindow->setCentralWidget(nullptr);
detachWindow->close();

Maybe it seems I have not changed the view's parent successfully but I can't fix the issue.
I will appreciate anyone if he will provide some helpful tips.
Thank you.
I tried googling and looked for several solutions but not worked for me.
Changing the QWidget parent while in a mousePressEvent ...
QWidget parent question

I cannot answer you about the specific problem, but in any case you should use takeCentralWidget(). The docs explicitly say that setCentralWidget() "takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time", so calling setCentralWidget() again is wrong if the previous widget must remain alive. Besides: 1. setting the SubWindow flag on QMdiSubWindow and reparenting its widget is redundant; 2. your code doesn't show how the subwindow is added to the mdi area.
